# Threaded Core Data

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, multithreading, core-data

I'm here to ask you how should I use threaded core data. I'm going to do it as

make `ManageObjectContext` for every controller class which is calling Database methods. This I 'll get by passing controller name as parameter in methods. And in my Database class. I've a shared `ManageObjectContext` and a dictionary in which I'll set `ManageObjectContext` for controller to retrieve or to set. Can you guys tell me if there is any drawback for it. One that I've noticed is all `ManageObjectContexts` will be in memory for all times. If someone can provide any other approach plz sugest. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Core Data threading is hard.  Fortunately, there is an [entire guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdConcurrency.html) available that documents how to manage concurrency in Core Data.

Whether or not memory usage is problematic is only something that can be answered by measuring memory usage, typically with the Allocations Instrument.   A managed object context, in and of itself, is fairly cheap.   The real question to answer is how much of the managed objects themselves (really, the data contained within) are *copied* between those contexts.   Instruments also has Core Data specific instrumentation that can be very useful.

Comment: Note: The guide is somewhat outdated and does not cover the queue confinement model introduced in iOS 5 - which is what you really should be using at this point.

Comment: @quellish It mentions queue quite heavily and alludes to the NSManagedObjectContext specific documentation, which has queue based API.  There is heavy use of the word "thread", but thread and queue are largely interchangeable in the context of modeling concurrency (queues provide a very light weight model for providing concurrency that is decouple from threads, but the *actual* concurrent behavior-- and problems therein -- are largely the same, algorithmically).

Comment: So if i use dictioarny and set contexts for every controller will not cost too much memory?

Comment: @bbum Specifically, it does not cover the use of the NSManagedObjectContext concurrency types introduced in iOS 5. The recently revised NSManagedObjectContext class reference does, as do several WWDC sessions